# Can i use JCheckbox to show "mixed state"

Tags: java, mixed, jcheckbox

In windows it is possible to show a grayed out JCheckbox, to show that the collection of data which it represents not all items have the same value.

Is this even possible with a JCheckBox?
How do i go about this?
(Hoping there's a way to not override it)

Thanks

Comment: Just an FYI - Grayed out usually signifies disabled in UI design, and it could be a confusion to your users if you use it to signify something else.  I have seen, in the past, people show the checkbox in one of two states (either selected or deselected) when there is a mixed state, and leave it to the user to determine whether it should be selected or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My colleague who this question came from thought of this;

1. Create a dummy JCheckBox which is disabled and selected. set the same size as the real one.
2. Create an Icon which' paint method actually paints the dummy JCheckbox.
3. Set the original JCheckBox' Icon to the one painting the dummy.
4. Remove the icon as soon as the JCheckBox is clicked.

++ No overridden JCheckBox

-- not a real tri-state Combo

I think he's satisfied.
Thanks for the help

Answer (score 2):

[JIDE Common Layer](http://www.jidesoft.com/products/oss.htm) has a [TristateCheckBox](http://www.jidesoft.com/javadoc/com/jidesoft/swing/TristateCheckBox.html).

Answer (score 1):

It's possible with some of work.

I have this code from some years ago. Is based in some examples I found in internet, but I cannot find any reference to the original creator, so I apologize

```
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeListener;
import javax.swing.plaf.ActionMapUIResource;
import java.awt.event.*;

/**
 * Maintenance tip - There were some tricks to getting this code
 * working:
 * 
 * 1. You have to overwite addMouseListener() to do nothing
 * 2. You have to add a mouse event on mousePressed by calling
 * super.addMouseListener()
 * 3. You have to replace the UIActionMap for the keyboard event
 * "pressed" with your own one.
 * 4. You have to remove the UIActionMap for the keyboard event
 * "released".
 * 5. You have to grab focus when the next state is entered,
 * otherwise clicking on the component won't get the focus.
 * 6. You have to make a TristateDecorator as a button model that
 * wraps the original button model and does state management.
 */
public class TristateCheckBox extends JCheckBox {
  /** This is a type-safe enumerated type */
  public static class State { private State() { } }
  public static final State NOT_SELECTED = new State();
  public static final State SELECTED = new State();
  public static final State DONT_CARE = new State();

  private final TristateDecorator model;

  public TristateCheckBox(String text, Icon icon, State initial){
    super(text, icon);
    // Add a listener for when the mouse is pressed
    super.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
      public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
        grabFocus();
        model.nextState();
      }
    });
    // Reset the keyboard action map
    ActionMap map = new ActionMapUIResource();
    map.put("pressed", new AbstractAction() {
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        grabFocus();
        model.nextState();
      }
    });
    map.put("released", null);
    SwingUtilities.replaceUIActionMap(this, map);
    // set the model to the adapted model
    model = new TristateDecorator(getModel());
    setModel(model);
    setState(initial);
  }
  public TristateCheckBox(String text, State initial) {
    this(text, null, initial);
  }
  public TristateCheckBox(String text) {
    this(text, DONT_CARE);
  }
  public TristateCheckBox() {
    this(null);
  }

  /** No one may add mouse listeners, not even Swing! */
  public void addMouseListener(MouseListener l) { }
  /**
   * Set the new state to either SELECTED, NOT_SELECTED or
   * DONT_CARE.  If state == null, it is treated as DONT_CARE.
   */
  public void setState(State state) { model.setState(state); }
  /** Return the current state, which is determined by the
   * selection status of the model. */
  public State getState() { return model.getState(); }
  public void setSelected(boolean b) {
    if (b) {
      setState(SELECTED);
    } else {
      setState(NOT_SELECTED);
    }
  }
  /**
   * Exactly which Design Pattern is this?  Is it an Adapter,
   * a Proxy or a Decorator?  In this case, my vote lies with the
   * Decorator, because we are extending functionality and
   * "decorating" the original model with a more powerful model.
   */
  private class TristateDecorator implements ButtonModel {
    private final ButtonModel other;
    private TristateDecorator(ButtonModel other) {
      this.other = other;
    }
    private void setState(State state) {
      if (state == NOT_SELECTED) {
        other.setArmed(false);
        setPressed(false);
        setSelected(false);
      } else if (state == SELECTED) {
        other.setArmed(false);
        setPressed(false);
        setSelected(true);
      } else { // either "null" or DONT_CARE
        other.setArmed(true);
        setPressed(true);
        setSelected(true);
      }
    }
    /**
     * The current state is embedded in the selection / armed
     * state of the model.
     * 
     * We return the SELECTED state when the checkbox is selected
     * but not armed, DONT_CARE state when the checkbox is
     * selected and armed (grey) and NOT_SELECTED when the
     * checkbox is deselected.
     */
    private State getState() {
      if (isSelected() && !isArmed()) {
        // normal black tick
        return SELECTED;
      } else if (isSelected() && isArmed()) {
        // don't care grey tick
        return DONT_CARE;
      } else {
        // normal deselected
        return NOT_SELECTED;
      }
    }
    /** We rotate between NOT_SELECTED, SELECTED and DONT_CARE.*/
    private void nextState() {
      State current = getState();
      if (current == NOT_SELECTED) {
        setState(SELECTED);
      } else if (current == SELECTED) {
        setState(DONT_CARE);
      } else if (current == DONT_CARE) {
        setState(NOT_SELECTED);
      }
    }
    /** Filter: No one may change the armed status except us. */
    public void setArmed(boolean b) {
    }
    /** We disable focusing on the component when it is not
     * enabled. */
    public void setEnabled(boolean b) {
      setFocusable(b);
      other.setEnabled(b);
    }
    /** All these methods simply delegate to the "other" model
     * that is being decorated. */
    public boolean isArmed() { return other.isArmed(); }
    public boolean isSelected() { return other.isSelected(); }
    public boolean isEnabled() { return other.isEnabled(); }
    public boolean isPressed() { return other.isPressed(); }
    public boolean isRollover() { return other.isRollover(); }
    public void setSelected(boolean b) { other.setSelected(b); }
    public void setPressed(boolean b) { other.setPressed(b); }
    public void setRollover(boolean b) { other.setRollover(b); }
    public void setMnemonic(int key) { other.setMnemonic(key); }
    public int getMnemonic() { return other.getMnemonic(); }
    public void setActionCommand(String s) {
      other.setActionCommand(s);
    }
    public String getActionCommand() {
      return other.getActionCommand();
    }
    public void setGroup(ButtonGroup group) {
      other.setGroup(group);
    }
    public void addActionListener(ActionListener l) {
      other.addActionListener(l);
    }
    public void removeActionListener(ActionListener l) {
      other.removeActionListener(l);
    }
    public void addItemListener(ItemListener l) {
      other.addItemListener(l);
    }
    public void removeItemListener(ItemListener l) {
      other.removeItemListener(l);
    }
    public void addChangeListener(ChangeListener l) {
      other.addChangeListener(l);
    }
    public void removeChangeListener(ChangeListener l) {
      other.removeChangeListener(l);
    }
    public Object[] getSelectedObjects() {
      return other.getSelectedObjects();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the effort!
But i'm looking for a way not to override it.
Sorry for not mentioning it

Comment: The normal `JCheckBox` can not do it. You have to roll your own and extending `JCheckBox` is the easiest way to do that.